# Android Java - Unable to destroy activity: IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, indexoutofboundsexception

I am getting the following error whenever I close my application:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: uk.cal.codename.projectnedry, PID: 24450
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {uk.cal.codename.projectnedry/uk.CompanyScope.CompanyNavigationActivity.CompanyNavigationActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4203)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4221)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap6(ActivityThread.java)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1538)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
   Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
      at java.util.ArrayList.set(ArrayList.java:427)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.makeInactive(FragmentManager.java:1662)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1452)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchDestroy(FragmentManager.java:2951)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchDestroy(FragmentController.java:271)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onDestroy(FragmentActivity.java:390)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onDestroy(AppCompatActivity.java:209)
      at uk.genericmodelviewpresenter.GenericMvpActivity.onDestroy(GenericMvpActivity.java:96)
      at uk.CompanyScope.CompanyNavigationActivity.CompanyNavigationActivity.onDestroy(CompanyNavigationActivity.java:523)
      at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:6881)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1153)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4190)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4221) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap6(ActivityThread.java) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1538) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

The only parts that touch code that I have written are:

CompanyNavigationActivity:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    getSpecificImpOfGenericPresenter().closeRealm();
}
```

and its superclass GenericMvpActivity:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    //Unbind Butterknife bindings
    if(mUnbinder!=null) {
        mUnbinder.unbind();
    }
}
```

From looking at the stacktrace I can see it is something fragment related, but this is within the Android code. This CompanyNavigationActivity does at times contain a number of fragments, <s>but the error occurs whether they are created or not</s>.

Any ideas as to what the cause is?

**EDIT 1**

The closeRealm method in the presenter class, simply removes listeners and closes the presenters instance of realm.

```
public void closeRealm() {
    this.mRealmDatabase.getInstance().removeAllChangeListeners();
    this.mRealmDatabase.close();
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Upon further testing it seems that if I create fragments held within a viewpager in my CompanyNavigationActivity this error **does not** occur. It seems to occur only when there are no fragments present within the activity.

**EDIT 3**

I have narrowed it down to a particular method, which is starting a foreground service. More specifically, the startService call.

```
     /**
     * If foreground location service is not running, start it
     */
    private void startLocationService() {
        if (!ForegroundLocationService.IS_SERVICE_RUNNING) {
            Intent service = new Intent(getSpecificImpOfGenericView().getApplicationContext(), ForegroundLocationService.class);
            service.setAction(ServiceConstants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION);
            ForegroundLocationService.IS_SERVICE_RUNNING = true;
            getSpecificImpOfGenericView().getApplicationContext().startService(service);
        }
    }
```

Surely a foreground request should remain in the foreground, as a separate service, and not affect the destruction of the activity that started them?

Comment: what is on `CompanyNavigationActivity.java:523`

Comment: error is at **getSpecificImpOfGenericPresenter().closeRealm();**

Comment: The error occurs at **super.onDestroy();**

Comment: @Calco what does this do `getSpecificImpOfGenericPresenter()`

Comment: It allows the View to call the closeRealm()  method in the Presenter class.

Comment: @Calco can you show us

Comment: Added as an edit to main question

Comment: put closeRealm code in try catch and before calling removeAllChangeListeners check if there are any listeners or not/

Comment: I can completely remove the closeRealm() call and the error is still present.  I am confident that closeRealm() is not causing the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You should do all the job before `super.onDestroy();`
Destroy the instance specific resources first, before destroying superclass resources that the instance specific resources may depend upon makes sense.

Comment: I have followed your advice, however this does not fix the current issue